# Coloured Text to highlight emphasis

Tags: support, text-formatting

In [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058094/why-is-virtualenv-venv-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04) post, the op has used colour to highlight aspects of his question to very good effect.

How is that achieved? I can't seem to find a reference as to how it is done and the menu bar at the head of the text body doesn't provide any clues...

Comment: That particular instance might look good, but just as often spurious syntax highlighting could make output hard to read

Comment: I doubt it helps, but as it doesn’t do any harm in this case I refrained from editing it out (by adding `<!-- language-all: none -->` to the post’s top).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt this is intentional – it‘s syntax highlighting, which in this case was added automatically when the question was tagged [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python), see [its Tag Info page](https://askubuntu.com/tags/python/info):

> Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): lang-py

The [syntax highlighting help page](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) explains how one can add this highlighting to one or all code blocks.

Further reading:

- [Help on syntax highlighting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)
- [meta.SE post explaining tag-based syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: Yep, 100% this.